# ReactJS - create-react-app try to import images in my project (wihout calling them)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have a ReactJS project where I want to display logo for products. In my assets file (./src/assets/images/logo/other/) I got all my images ZZZ.png for example.

But now, I delete these png and they are no more available in ./src/assets/images/logo/other/

I don't import the image directly in my project, but I have a simple structure like that.

```
export const fetchLogo = (product) => {

  var logoPath = require(`../assets/images/logo/noLogo.png`);
 
  try {
    logoPath = require(`../assets/images/logo/other/${product}.png`);
    return logoPath;
  } catch {}

  return logoPath;
};

fetchLogo("ZZZ") // return noLogo.png
```

So basically, for the product ZZZ, if there is no image ZZZ.png, the function will return the logoPath for noLogo.png (which work fine).

But when I compiled my project (npm start - with CRA 5.0.1) and I don't call the product ZZZ, I got :

```
WARNING in ./src/assets/images/logo/other/ sync ^\.\/.*\.png$ ./ZZZ.png
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ZZZ.png' in 'C:\Users\ my path here'
```

The warning is for all previous .png I delete (8398 warnings)

So how CRA now that ZZZ.png is needed if I don't ask for it ? And how CRA knows I may require it dynamically ? Is there a "cache" that knows the picture ZZZ.png was here before ?

I'm sure the "problem" come from Webpack and/or CRA, but my ReactJS level are quite low.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of your cache causing this issue. To solve it clear npm cache .Run this command in terminal:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Clear cache of your browser go to *Inspect*-> *Application* ->*Storage* -> *Local Storage* -> inside it right click on your web url and press *clear*.

Comment: Yes it's definetely that, I try the following : npm cache clean // Add picture in ./logo // npm start // Delete picture // npm start and I got the missing dependency for the picture I just delete. Thanks !

Comment: @Thomas Worked?